Upperbound on integral of concave power of Gaussians
During some calculations I came across an integral of the following form where $0<m<1$ and where $a$ is a positive constant.
$$I(m,a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{(z-a)^2}{2}\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{(z+a)^2}{2}\right)\right]^mdz$$
So far I realized that I can use the subadditivity of $x \mapsto x^m$ and Gaussian integration to get an upper bound which is sharp enough for $a$ non-zero. However, when $a=0$ this upper bound is sadly too large. Does anyone have any idea how to evaluate / upper bound this integral properly?

Taking Wei's answer further:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
 I(m,a) & = & \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[\exp\Bigl(-\frac{(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr)+\exp\Bigl(-\frac{(z+a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\right]^m\,{\rm d}z \\[7pt]
 & = & \displaystyle 2\int_0^\infty \left[\exp\Bigl(-\frac{(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr)+\exp\Bigl(-\frac{(z+a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\right]^m \,{\rm d}z \\[7pt]
& = & \displaystyle 2\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl(-\frac{m(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\left[1+\exp\Bigl(\frac{(z-a)^2}{2}-\frac{(z+a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\right]^m \,{\rm d}z \\[7pt]
& = & \displaystyle 2\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl(-\frac{m(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\left[1+\exp(-2az)\right]^m \,{\rm d}z \\[7pt]
& = & \displaystyle 2^{m+1}\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigr(-\frac{m(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr)\left[1-\frac{1-\exp(-2az)}{2}\right]^m {\rm d}z \\[7pt] & \le & \displaystyle 2^{m+1}\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl(-\frac{m(z-a)^2}{2}\Bigr){\rm d}z \\[7pt]
 & = & \displaystyle 2^{m+1}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2m}} \left[1+{\rm erf}\Bigl(\,a\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\,\Bigl)\right]
\end{array} $$

Is it possible that at the end it should be -erf? And thanks a lot for your answer I did not consider splitting them like that at all.

According to W|A it's +erf. I imagine you translate z (substitution) to get an int from -a to inf, which is the same as -inf to a by symmetry, and then split off the -inf to 0 part for the constant 1, but I didn't check. Also, yes: we have expansions for $(1+x)^m$ (binomial) and e.g. $\ln(1+x)$ (Mercator) but can't apply directly to $(A+B)^m$ or $\ln(A+B)$, we have to "dehomogenize" them by factoring $(A+B)=A(1+B/A)$ with $B\le A$.

$$I(m,0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2^m \exp\left(-\frac{mz^2}2\right)dz=2^m\sqrt\frac{2\pi}m.$$
